# Why can I replace a new fragment but not a initialized fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This is my custom Fragment:

Interface:

```
public interface NotVerifiedWifiCardFragment{
    void loadSSIDName(String ssid);

    void setArguments(Bundle bundle);
}
```

Class:

```
public class NotVerifiedWifiCardFragmentImpl extends Fragment implements NotVerifiedWifiCardFragment {

    private TextView ssid;
    private View view;

    //@Inject
    //NotVerifiedWifiCardPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
        super.setArguments(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_connected_not_verified, null);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        ssid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_not_verified_wifi_ssid);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        ssid.setText(bundle.getString("SSID"));
        //presenter.setView(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void loadSSIDName(String ssid) {
        this.ssid.setText(ssid);
    }
}
```

When I replace a new CustomFragment with FragmentTransaction I can do it without any problem:

```
@Override
    public void showNotVerifiedWifiCard(String ssid) {
        // Begin the transaction
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace the contents of the container with the new fragment
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up_anim, R.anim.slide_down_anim);
        ft.replace(R.id.main_small_card, new NotVerifiedWifiCardFragmentImpl());

        // or ft.add(R.id.your_placeholder, new FooFragment());
        // Complete the changes added above
        ft.commit();
    }
```

But when I try to call the Fragment Transaction with the same fragment but initialized (to pass a Bundle), replace method doesn't allow me. How do you solve it when you need to pass a bundle with data?

```
@Override
    public void showNotVerifiedWifiCard(String ssid) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("SSID", ssid);

        NotVerifiedWifiCardFragment fm = new NotVerifiedWifiCardFragmentImpl();
        fm.setArguments(bundle);

        // Begin the transaction
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace the contents of the container with the new fragment
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up_anim, R.anim.slide_down_anim);
        ft.replace(R.id.main_small_card, fm);

        // or ft.add(R.id.your_placeholder, new FooFragment());
        // Complete the changes added above
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Probably it is a silly object oriented concexpt misunderstood.

EDIT: Error show is:

Error: Wrong 2nd argument type. Found:'com.blabla.NotVerifiedWifiCardFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'

Comment: `ft.replace(R.id.main_small_card, ft);`   second argument ft is a typo? should be fm.

Comment: What error you get? Maybe @marcinj is right and it's just a typo :)

Comment: It's wrong, It should be fm. I'll correct it! Thank you.

Comment: Error: Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.blabla.NotVerifiedWifiCardFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since not any object implementing the `NotVerifiedWifiCardFragment` is actually a fragment (you can declare any object class and make it implement this protocol), you can't treat NotVerifiedWifiCardFragment as a Fragment (the name you gave the interface is mistaking).

For example:

```
class Test implements NotVerifiedWifiCardFragment {
void loadSSIDName(String ssid){}

void setArguments(Bundle bundle){}
....
}
```

Test is just a simple class, not a fragment.

A quick solution would be replacing

```
NotVerifiedWifiCardFragment fm = new NotVerifiedWifiCardFragmentImpl();
```

with

```
NotVerifiedWifiCardFragmentImpl fm = new NotVerifiedWifiCardFragmentImpl()
```

What you really want in that case is to create an abstract **Fragment** **class** called `NotVerifiedWifiCardFragment` and make other fragments extend it.

**Example code**

```
abstract class NotVerifiedWifiCardFragment extends Fragment {
     abstract void loadSSIDName(String ssid);
     abstract void setArguments(Bundle bundle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you can try to use

`public static Fragment instantiate(Context context, String fname, @Nullable Bundle args)`

like this :

```
NotVerifiedWifiCardFragment fm = (NotVerifiedWifiCardFragment) Fragment.instantiate(context, "some_name", your_args);
```